# Why does bash need special characters to pad integer math and variables?

Tags: bash

```
count=0
while [ "$count" -lt $var1Length  ]
do


count=$((count+1))
done
```

Above I need to do increment my count so bizarrely. I've seen other posts relating to this but hitting on the head. It's just so wacky, I need a real play by play of the interpreter I guess. It just doesn't make sense.

Also,

> while [ "$count"

bash can't just read $count without quotes reliably? What is it expecting after the dollar that would make it mis-read this $count?

Comment: Historical reasons. Try `count=-f` to see how things break without double quotes.

Comment: XD Nice one. Let me try some more things... thanks

Comment: In fact, $variables in the shell are not variables but macros or template markers to expand.

Comment: @choroba Have you tested this? The behavior with `count=-f` is entirely unaffected by quoting (outside the extremely unusual case that `$IFS` contains `-` or `f`). After `count=-f`, both `[ "$count" -lt 10 ]` and `[ $count -lt 10 ]` give "integer expression expected" and all of `[ -f /bin/ls ]`, `[ "$count" /bin/ls ]`, and `[ $count /bin/ls ]` have the same effect. `[` is a command; it never sees the quotes, due to quote removal. (In contrast, `[[` is a keyword, which lets it have its own special quoting rules. But it doesn't treat `$count` and `"$count"` differently in these examples either.)

Answer (score 1):

Another (simpler) way, using *bashism*:

```
count=0
while ((count < var1Length)); do
    ((count++))
done
```

or even

```
count=0
while ((count++ < var1Length)); do
    # ...
done
```

`((...))` is an arithmetic command, which returns an exit status of 0 if the expression is nonzero, or 1 if the expression is zero. Also used as a synonym for "let", if side effects (assignments) are needed. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression

Comment: or just while ((count++ < var1Length))

Comment: Or `for ((count = 0; count < var1Length; count++))`. Unlike `while ((...))`, which is an ordinary `while` loop whose condition is an arithmetic evaluation command, this is a separate form of the `for` loop, since `((...; ...; ...))` is not a valid command on its own. [Bash supports this alternate form of a `for` loop, as well as the more common form.](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Looping-Constructs) I considered putting this in a separate answer and I don't know if you'd consider it to be in the scope of what you're saying here, but I think it would be reasonable here.

Comment: Not valid ? Test this: `for ((; ;)); do echo -n '.'; sleep .2; done`

Comment: @GillesQuenot That works in Bash. (I've just tested it in Bash 5.0.17, but this form of the `for` loop is not new.) What shell and version did you test it with?